# How to view all object property details within the window object in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know that the following can be used to get the object list within the window object in the chrome dev tools console:

```
for (var prop in window)
    console.log(prop);
```

If I want to view the values held by these properties  for these window objects, how do i view these?

Is there quick way to look at these within the chrome dev tools or any other ways that you guys use in general?

Comment: Not sure what you  mean, why couldn't you just do `console.log(window)` and expand the object in the console, looking at whatever you want ?

Comment: When i run the above piece of code, there is no option to expand the object although i know what you are trying to say

Comment: What do you mean? When running this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/goawuxb9/) in Chrome, don't you get an object with little arrows on the left side that you can click to expand ?

Comment: try `console.dir(object)`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, both the fiddle and console.dir() worked. I was using a for loop to iterate over the list of window objects in which case it did not give me a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there quick way to look at these within the chrome dev tools or any other ways that you guys use in general?

Don't use "console.log", chrome has useful tools to debug your web app.

See the chrome's debugger : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Tutorial: http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/05/javascript-debugging-with-chrome.html

Example:

[image]

Comment: Very valuable resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just type it in the Dev Tools console.

`window` logs the window object

`document` logs the document object

And you can move down the object tree from there, like document.getElementById(), or window.alert() or what have you.

[image: Dev Tools window object]

To get Dev Tools, open the Chrome Menu in the upper-right-hand corner of the browser window and select More Tools > Developer Tools. You can also use Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux)

I suppose it would be slightly nice to have just an icon you can click but I guess Google figured that writing the word 'window' was minor enough, and I tend to agree.